# How to select all elements with a specific attribute? with TinyXPath

Tags: xml, xpath, tinyxpath

What is the XPath expression for selecting all elements with attribute A?

```
const char* xpath = "//\*/\*[@A]"
```

Comment: Not sure about the need to escape the `*`, but your current XPath is selecting all elements that have an `@A` and are children of an element, so it would match for most elements but you would miss the document element if it had an A attribute(since it won't have a parent element).

Answer (score 214, accepted):

This XPath selects all elements that have an A attribute:

```
//*[@A]
```